# Linux Ubuntu crash & errors during boot

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, crash, system-recovery

Ubuntu 16.04LTS, system crashes during boot with multiple errors.
How to fix and recover system? (in details)
Info:

[pic1](https://ibb.co/f2bdQcG)
[pic2](https://ibb.co/3v0ZXBV)
[pic3](https://ibb.co/6YhnM2t)

[image]

Comment: It seems that your disk died. Before doing anything else shutdown the system and try to `ddrescue` (or similar tools) to a different disk in order to save as much as possible. If that doesn't work you hopefully have a backup. After all that you can try to do as you're told and try a `fsck` but I'm not confident that it will resolve anything, to be honest.

Comment: I'm not sure if `ddrescue` has been installed on ubuntu laptop.

Comment: No, you remove the disk and plug it to a different computer. It seems like you're not very familiar with all this, maybe try to find someone who can help you where you are? With these operations there's a risk of data loss (maybe there already is if the disk actually died) so you should really know what you're doing.

Comment: I can remove disk and put it into an external usb 2.0 HDD Enclosure, I have another laptop with Win7, but not linux.

Comment: Then you'll have to use an equivalent on Windows, I don't know simiar tools for windows.

Comment: Ok, I have to replace the disk and install new system, then copy files from old disk. Its not fully clear what is benefits of using `ddrescue`  if I need selectively copy a particular files from the old disk to new.

Comment: ddrescue is able to copy intact sectors from a failed device. It’s possible that you won’t be able to get the data off your drive with regular tools.